# See the div relative to the price of the product?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to ask how to put some kind of restriction to be displayed a certain wild items over 150 Bulgarian Leva (BGN)

As the price it out like so:

```
<em id="price2" class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">2.54лв</em>
```

I like over 150лв. to display the another div

```
<div id="another">
text
</div>
```

Comment: be clear with your specifiactions

Comment: Ok i write the specifiactions

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using an if-else construct.

```
if ($price > 150) {
    echo 'this';
}
else {
    echo 'that';
}
```

Comment: pls tell me jquery variant

Comment: Take away the $ from before the variable and change the `echo` to the jQuery/JS equivalent. Standard Javascript will do, there is no separate if/else construct for jQuery. http://css-plus.com/2011/07/jquery-if-else-statements/